# Automate function creating rolling window of dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a several data frames df1, df2, ... dfn saved in the same folder that I would like to concatenate using a rolling window of n. So for n=2, I put df1 in a separate folder and wrote the following loop that concatenates d1+d2, df2+df3, df3+4 and so on.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\myinputfilepath\startingfile\df1.xlsx')
inputfilepath = r'C:\myinputfilepath\*.xlsx'

for file in glob.iglob(inputfilepath):
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file)
    dfcombined = pd.concat([df,df2])
    df = df2
```

This works perfectly, and in a similar way I can concatenate three data frames at the same time, so that I get df1+df2+df3, df2+df3+d4 and so on using this code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\myinputfilepath\startingfile\df1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\myinputfilepath\startingfile\df2.xlsx')    

for file in glob.iglob(inputfilepath):
    df3 = pd.read_excel(file)
    dfcombined = pd.concat([d1,df2,df3])
    df1 = df2
    df2 = df3
```

My question now: what is the most efficient way to automate this so that I can put the loop in a function and give n, the size of the window, as one of the argument as ideally I would like not to edit the folder and manually move the starting files every single time.

All kinds of suggestions are very welcome.